# React-Leaflet Search Box Implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, open-source, react-leaflet

Are there any resources showing a search box implementation with react-leaflet?

I'd like to have my **map pins** populate upon a **search** result that would query and retrieve my existing data.

ie:

```
const names = [

  {name: 'Joe', location: '40.734621, -73.989341 '},
  {name: 'Seth', location: '45.77621, -73.789654 '},

]
```

Then, after searching for Joe or Seth, the map would populate with the location coordinates.

I found examples for leaflet.js but couldn't find any examples spun with react-leaflet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [leaflet-geosearch](https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch)

Install it with `npm install --save leaflet-geosearch`

Then you just need to  build a component with it:

```
import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

class Search extends MapControl {

  createLeafletElement() {
    return GeoSearchControl({
      provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
      style: 'bar',
      showMarker: true,
      showPopup: false,
      autoClose: true,
      retainZoomLevel: false,
      animateZoom: true,
      keepResult: false,
      searchLabel: 'search'
    });
  }
}

export default Search;
```

And use your component in your Map:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Map>
      (...)
      <Search />
    </Map>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll start implementing this

Comment: Thanks, but how to append the search result in this Map?

Comment: @QauseenMZ These are the docs: https://smeijer.github.io/leaflet-geosearch  you can read the providers section to learn about how to implement search providers.

Answer (score 6):

I think I found a much easier way of doing this without needing to create and extend a class.

```js
import { Map, useLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet'
import { OpenStreetMapProvider, GeoSearchControl } from 'leaflet-geosearch'

// make new leaflet element
const Search = (props) => {
    const { map } = useLeaflet() // access to leaflet map
    const { provider } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
            provider,
        })

        map.addControl(searchControl) // this is how you add a control in vanilla leaflet
        return () => map.removeControl(searchControl)
    }, [props])

    return null // don't want anything to show up from this comp
}


export default function Map() {
  return (
    <Map {...otherProps}>
      {...otherChildren}
      <Search provider={new OpenStreetMapProvider()} />
    </Map>

  )
}
```

Comment: This is great, very helpful to me. One point to add is that if using the new v3 of react-leaflet, you will need to import useMap and not useLeaflet (deprecated).

Comment: @EricFurspan would you be kind enough to share your code? I am not able to make this work with react-leaflet v3. I also substituted `<Map />` with `<MapContainer />`. It gives me error `map is undefined`, referring to the line where the mapControl is being added

Comment: @Phlame I'd be glad to help. I only ask that you to put your question into its own post and send me its link and I will provide an answer to it with code. This post was already answered so let's not pollute it.

Comment: @EricFurspan Hi, I figured it out in the end! Thanks for your willingness to help though!

Answer (score 4):

```
import { Map} from 'react-leaflet'
import { OpenStreetMapProvider, GeoSearchControl } from 'leaflet-geosearch'

// make new leaflet element
const Search = (props) => {
    const map = useMap() // access to leaflet map
    const { provider } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
            provider,
        })

        map.addControl(searchControl) // this is how you add a control in vanilla leaflet
        return () => map.removeControl(searchControl)
    }, [props])

    return null // don't want anything to show up from this comp
}


export default function Map() {
  return (
    <MapContainer {...otherProps}>
      {...otherChildren}
      <Search provider={new OpenStreetMapProvider()} />
    </MapContainer >

  )
}
```

This is if you are using MapContainer instead of map

Comment: I have tried this in react-leaflet 4, and got the following:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.trim is not a function
    at g (resultList.ts:73:1)
    at NewClass.onSubmit (SearchControl.ts:391:1)
    at NewClass.selectResult (SearchControl.ts:338:1)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (SearchControl.ts:231:1)

Answer (score 1):

Solution That Worked while Using MapContainer.
[Leaflet.GeoSearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-geosearch#using-with-react-leaflet)

```
npm i leaflet-geosearch
```

The Use the following the code.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
// Search Location
import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider  } from "leaflet-geosearch";
import { useMap, MapContainer  } from "react-leaflet";

/**
 * Search Location 
 */

 const SearchLocation = (props) => {
  // Get access to leaflet map
  const { provider } = props;

  // Get search control
  const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
    provider: provider,
  });

  //   Access Leaflet Map
  const map = useMap(props);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Add searchControl to Leaflet map
    map.addControl(searchControl);
    return () => map.removeControl(searchControl);
  });

  return null; // Do not render any thing
}

// Call SearchLocation in MyMap

const MyMap = () => {
  // ...
  return (
    <MapContainer>
       <SearchLocation provider={new OpenStreetMapProvider()} />
      {/* ... */}
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```