# Search Box implementation in React-leaflet v3.1.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am trying to implement a `searchbox` feature in my react app. But getting this error "Attempted import error: 'MapControl' is not exported from 'react-leaflet'" in the new version of react-leaflet

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Polygon, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import "./index.css";

// Cordinates of Marcillac
const center = [45.269169177925754, -0.5231516014256281]
const purpleOptions = { color: 'white' }

class MapWrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="mapid">
                <MapContainer center={center} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
                    <TileLayer
                        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
                        url='https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
                    />
                </MapContainer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MapWrapper;
```

The implementation given here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290555/react-leaflet-search-box-implementation` doesnt work as `MapControl` is depricted.

Tried 2nd solution as well.

```
import { Map, useLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet'
import { OpenStreetMapProvider, GeoSearchControl } from 'leaflet-geosearch'

// make new leaflet element
const Search = (props) => {
    const { map } = useLeaflet() // access to leaflet map
    const { provider } = props

    useEffect(() => {
        const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
            provider,
        })

        map.addControl(searchControl) // this is how you add a control in vanilla leaflet
        return () => map.removeControl(searchControl)
    }, [props])

    return null // don't want anything to show up from this comp
}


export default function Map() {
  return (
    <Map {...otherProps}>
      {...otherChildren}
      <Search provider={new OpenStreetMapProvider()} />
    </Map>

  )
}
```

Here I get map.addControl is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You have just confused react-leaflet versions.

The way you are doing it would be correct in react-leaflet version 2.x

For react-leaflet v.3.x your custom comp should look like this:

```
function LeafletgeoSearch() {
  const map = useMap(); //here use useMap hook

  useEffect(() => {
    const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

    const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
      provider,
      marker: {
        icon
      }
    });

    map.addControl(searchControl);

    return () => map.removeControl(searchControl)
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

You can take the map reference from `useMap` hook instead of `useLeaflet`.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/search-box-implementation-in-react-leaflet-v310-sx0rp?file=/src/MapWrapper.jsx)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works except for the drop down value are invisible while typing in search box. I will debug it.